# map objects in multidimensional array javascript react native based on column index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I have a two history objects that are podcasts and articles, i want to display both in the same screen in descending order by which time they were clicked,

Here are the variables of original article and podcast from DB

```
var { articles, articlesInHistory, podcastsInHistory, podcasts } = this.props.stores.appStore;
```

Here is my article Object from history: console.log("dataItem", articlesInHistory)

```
dataItem Array [
  Object {
    "currentTime": 1585439646,
    "id": "156701",
    Symbol(mobx administration): ObservableObjectAdministration {
      "defaultEnhancer": [Function deepEnhancer],
      "keysAtom": Atom {
        "diffValue": 0,
        "isBeingObserved": true,
        "isPendingUnobservation": false,
        "lastAccessedBy": 26,
        "lowestObserverState": 2,
        "name": "appStore@1.articlesInHistory[..].keys",
        "observers": Set {},
      },
      "name": "appStore@1.articlesInHistory[..]",
      "pendingKeys": Map {
        Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag) => false,
        "hasOwnProperty" => false,
        "toJSON" => false,
      },
      "proxy": [Circular],
      "target": Object {
        "currentTime": 1585439646,
        "id": "156701",
        Symbol(mobx administration): [Circular],
      },
      "values": Map {
        "id" => "156701",
        "currentTime" => 1585439646,
      },
    },
  },
  ,]
```

And podcast from history: console.log("dataItem", podcastsInHistory)

```
dataItem Array [
  Object {
    "currentTime": 1585439636,
    "id": "4",
    Symbol(mobx administration): ObservableObjectAdministration {
      "defaultEnhancer": [Function deepEnhancer],
      "keysAtom": Atom {
        "diffValue": 0,
        "isBeingObserved": true,
        "isPendingUnobservation": false,
        "lastAccessedBy": 26,
        "lowestObserverState": 2,
        "name": "appStore@1.podcastsInHistory[..].keys",
        "observers": Set {},
      },
      "name": "appStore@1.podcastsInHistory[..]",
      "pendingKeys": Map {
        Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag) => false,
        "hasOwnProperty" => false,
        "toJSON" => false,
      },
      "proxy": [Circular],
      "target": Object {
        "currentTime": 1585439636,
        "id": "4",
        Symbol(mobx administration): [Circular],
      },
      "values": Map {
        "id" => "4",
        "currentTime" => 1585439636,
      },
    },
  },
]
```

now i want to order the two components using currentTime in condition

for example if this podcast was first then i should return

```
<PodcastList navigate={navigate} podcast={podcast} key={index} />)
```

Or if the article is first then show

```
<SmallArticle key={index} article={article} />
```

i need them mixed not like articles on top and podcast bottom, i been searching arrays sort but couldn't solve it.

I want a condition based on currentTime and using an id to identify or match objects thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you don´t know from the data if its an article or a podcast (there is no attribute in your objects that tells you that), you can´t put them in the same list-array.

The only way to know if you should render an Article or a Podcast component is based on what list you are reading.

Keep two indexes, articleIndex = 0 and podcastIndex = 0 (you can keep that in your state), and read the actual article and podcast for respective list, and compare the current time. Then you will know what component to render, and advance the corresponding list index.

In pseudo code:

- while articleIndex < articlesList.length && podcastIndex < podcastList.length do:

  - if articlesList[articleIndex].currentTime < podcastList[pocastIndex].currentTime do:

    - render `<SmallArticle article={articlesList[articleIndex]} key ={articleIndex}/>`//render SmallArticle
    - articleIndex += 1; //advance index
  - else do:

    - render `<PodcastList podcast={podcastList[postcastIndex]} key={podcastIndex} />`
    - podcastIndex +=1;
- when the while statement finishes, is because one of the list has been fully traversed. You need to traverse the rest of the other and render the respect component.

If you show me some of your components code can help you with code in more detail, but I don´t know the context.

Comment: The objects are separate,